# How to hide textview when image view collapsed completely

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an image view, `height-264dp` and a text view in collapsible layout, when user scrolls up, image view starts going up, and at certain point it stops, and toolbar takes its place, the issue is that I want to remove textview when collapsible header scrolls up and toolbar comes in place.

This is my view, background blue color will be replace by some image.

[image]

and when user scrolls up, i need this type of view, background color will be replaced by some image, the part of image will always be visible.

[image]

This is my code, its collapsing fine, the only issue I am facing is that I am unable to hide textview, if it goes away, I am good.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_newsViewThumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="264dp"
                android:background="@drawable/event_home_bg"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/barlow_extrabold"
                android:shadowColor="#000000"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:text="This is a text VIEW That iwant to hide"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvHome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/barlow_bold"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.1"
                    android:text="HOME"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <include layout="@layout/content_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may delete this line

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
```

for your textview

Answer (score 0):

- You can listening `AppBarLayout OffsetChange` by `addOnOffsetChangedListener()` method. try like bellow.

  ```
      // Initializing collapsing toolbar
      final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
              (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
      collapsingToolbar.setTitle("----");
      AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
      appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

      // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
      appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
          boolean isShow = false;
          int scrollRange = -1;

          @Override
          public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
              if (scrollRange == -1) {
                  scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
              }
              if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                  collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                  isShow = true;
              } else if (isShow) {
                  collapsingToolbar.setTitle("----");
                  isShow = false;
              }
          }
      });
  ```